# Metric Coordinate system in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates, simulation, metrics

I am new in PyGame and I am working on simulating pedestrians and vehicles movements, However, I would like to have the values of objects' position and velocities in meters. So, is it possible to have a metric coordinate system with PyGame? and how? and if not, do you know a similar python simulation tool can meet this requirement?

Comment: Just assume that 1 unit in Pygame = 1m or 1cm if you need more precision

Comment: "metric" in computer simulations has little meaning, as long as all objects, distances, etc are scaled in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a game like Minecraft. Most people know the blocks are "one cubic meter" but only because the game devs have said so and everything *appears* that way. Units of measurement in gave development are largely arbitrary (just like the real world). You can make yourself what appears to be a 1-meter unit square in your game space and scale everything accordingly.

Creating a constant variable would probably be a good idea too

final int METER_IN_PIXELS = 20;

this way in any math you need to do it can be used as your unit meter

roadLength = 130 * METER_IN_PIXELS;   //130 meters long